# What would be the most efficient way to retopo this mesh?

Tags: modeling

Should I just make the low poly version by removing the modifiers then bake, or start from scratch like how most people retopo a human?[image: the mesh]
edit: I'm going to use it as a video game asset.

Comment: I don't see what you could bake as the shape is rather simple, it would make sense if you had a lot of small details, slots, bolts, holes, etc. Actually I'm sure you can use the current topology and make it cleaner, for example there are a lot of horizontal edges that don't seem very useful, or could be reduced by some tricks, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geometry looks OK. You do not need to retopologize this. It can be improved by editing and removing some loops or sliding some edges(Shift + V) and merging some vertices, but I don't think you need to do a lot here. Starting from scratch seems unnecessary for many purposes. Obviously, since you did not tell anything about your context or what you are planing to use it for, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm planing to use it as a video game asset, I'm not sure if the sub division modeling and baking it to a low poly was a "good" way to do it or not, but since the high poly mesh is already finished there's no going back anymore.

Comment: I think you need to kind of 'make' it low poly editing the current one. For example to remove the edge loops that form bevelled edges after subsurf and use bevels for them instead and remove all the geometry that does not contribute to the form. Or you could apply subsurf and then delete unnecessary loops as well... The level to which you need to do it depends on the poly count restrictions for your specific purpose.